# Error showing in C# Interop.Excel: A field in your source data has more unique items than can be used in a PivotTable report

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, office-interop

I have created Excel in C# and now when I am trying to insert Pivot table in another sheet, I am getting the following error:

> A field in your source data has more unique items than can be used in a PivotTable report. Microsoft Excel may not be able to create the report, or may create the report without the data from this field.

Please check below code which I am using to create pivot in excel

```cs
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook excelWorkBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath);
Excel.Worksheet excelworksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelWorkBook.Sheets[rowDataSheetIndex];
Excel.Worksheet sheet2 = (Excel.Worksheet)excelWorkBook.Sheets.Add();
sheet2.Name = sheetName;
excelworksheet.Activate();

Excel.Range oRange = excelworksheet.UsedRange;
Excel.PivotCache oPivotCache = excelWorkBook.PivotCaches().Add(Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlExternal, oRange);
Excel.Range oRange2 = (Excel.Range)sheet2.Cells[1, 1];
Excel.PivotCaches pch = excelWorkBook.PivotCaches();
pch.Add(Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, oRange).CreatePivotTable(sheet2.Cells[1, 1], sheetName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
Excel.PivotTable pvt = sheet2.PivotTables(sheetName) as Excel.PivotTable;
pvt.RefreshTable();

Excel.PivotField fld;
foreach (string rowlabel in listRowLabels)
{
    fld = ((Excel.PivotField)pvt.PivotFields(rowlabel));
    fld.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
    fld.set_Subtotals(1, true);
}

excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
sheet2.Activate();
sheet2.get_Range("A1", "A1").Select();
excelWorkBook.SaveAs(filePath);
excelWorkBook.Close();
excelApp.Quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this error has resulted from trying to put too much data into a pivot table.

How many rows are you trying to insert?  If it's [more than 32k](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4302-0141-0_9) that is likely your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) article says:

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

> If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

You may consider using the Open XML SDK instead, see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk). Or just use any third-party components designed for the server-side execution.